# HTML5 put base64 image to input file

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input file element:

```
<input id="field_photo" type="file" name="photo" value="" class="text" />
```

Can I put base64 image into it after pressing a button?

The base64 is in var `base64image=getBase64()`.

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: i have form to upload image to server, the image come from webcam which is encoded as base64, so i need to put it in that input file and send it

Comment: No you cannot. Instead use input `hidden` type and save your value to it

Comment: so i should proccess different way in the server side?

Comment: Not at all. Just do as you were expecting to do with the input file type. Just use `<input type="hidden" value="base64...">` field instead of `file`